# how to use pre-defined variables or constants in (custom-theme-set-faces) in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to use pre-defined variable or constant of string type in  `(custom-theme-set-faces)`, so it would go like

```
(setq Blue128 "#000080")
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'thename
 '(default ((t (
                        :background Blue128))))
)
```

If I try it formulated as above, I get type mismatch:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, Blue128
```

Also tried with `defvar`, `defconst`, `let`.
Looked for an answer in 'Emacs Manual' , 'Emacs Lisp Reference', and in 'Programming in Emacs Lisp'. Also in search engines.

What actually worked was:

```
(setq Blue128 "#000080")
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'thename
 '(default ((t (
                        :background "#000000"))))
)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background Blue128)
```

...which is not quite what I want.

'Face attributes' are in fact 'symbol properties', right? Looks like there is some subtlety with scope and/or 'evaluation order', but I can't find what it is.

Comment: I am having this same exact problem

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Made some progress since, once, but do not remember well enough how did it go. ))

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**: use a backquote and a comma instead of a quote.

The problem concerns the elisp `'(exp)` quote syntax: it tells the interpreter not to evaluate the following expression, but to treat it as a constant (which in this case is an expression to be evaluated later by `custom-theme-set-faces`, which will parse out its args and get their values).

Quoting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) on quoting:

> This provides a way to include constant symbols and lists, which are not self-evaluating objects

So, if I understand this correctly, the error we're getting happens somewhere in the guts of `custom-theme-set-faces` because it expects a literal `stringp`, not a symbol needing evaluation.

The answer is to use the  `` `(exp) `` backquote syntax, which does the same thing except allows you to specify elements you *do* want evaluated right away, using the accompanying `,symbol` comma syntax to mark what you need evaluated now. [Manual again](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

So your code should be:

```
(setq Blue128 "#000080")

(custom-theme-set-faces
 'thename
    `(default ((t (
        :background ,Blue128))))
)
```

This is a very late answer, but provided for the benefit of any other amateur elisp hackers...

Comment: Just checked, and this works. Subtle! We are to avoid 'thank you's, but thank you anyway.

Comment: you're welcome, anyway. :)